# Getting the error of null when running Bash C Program

Tags: c

Why am I getting null in the ptr variable at the end when I compile? I am trying to get the start time after the program terminates. The output says that "The code has successfully terminated" or the child has successfully terminated, but the ptr variable at the end is set to null. Can anyone hypothesis as to why this is?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int main(){
  const char *name = "OS";
  long *ptr;
  pid_t childPid;
  childPid = fork();
  int  shm;
  if(childPid == 0){
    char *args[] ={"ls","-l",NULL};
    int shmid;
    int shsize = 5000000;
    key_t key;

    char *s;
    key = 9876;
    if(shmid < 0){
      printf("error getting shmid");
      exit(1);
    }
    shm = shm_open(name,O_CREAT| O_RDWR,0666);
    if(shm == (char *) -1){
      printf("error getting shared memory");
      exit(1);}
    time_t startTime;
    gettimeofday(&startTime,0);
    ptr = (long *) mmap(0,sizeof(startTime),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,shm,0);
    ptr+=startTime;
    time_t endTime;
    execvp(args[0],args);
    printf("successfuly created child proceess");
    exit(0);
  }

  else if (childPid <0){
    printf("unsuccessfuly created child proccess");
  }
  else{
    int returnStatus;
    waitpid(childPid,&returnStatus,0);
    if(returnStatus == 0){
      printf("The chiild terminated normally");
      printf("%s",ptr);
      shm_unlink(name);
    }

    if(returnStatus == 1){

      printf("The child terminated with error");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: OMG, please do yourself a favor and format your program properly.

Comment: While things like indentation is irrelevant for the compiler, it's very much needed by humans attempting to read your code. I also doubt you need *all* those header files. And the code you show won't even build. Please create a [mcve] that replicates your problem that you copy-paste into the question. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why is there a line that reads `"hello.c" 65L, 1168C` in the middle of your code?

Comment: a vim statusline, apparently

Comment: I suspect a big problem during the copy / paste ^^ Code indented, missing } added and extra line removed.

Comment: I would bet there is a `fork()` missing somewhere in that mess...

Answer (score 0):

Your manipulated the wrong way on ptr pointer. When use it please use the deference operator *

this line:

```
ptr+=startTime;
```

should be

*ptr += startTime;

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- you have the following code testing on an uninitialised variable:

  ```
  if(shmid < 0){
      printf("error getting shmid");
      exit(1);
  }
  ```

  in the child process, so you'll get erratic behaviour as `shmid` will get rubbish and sometimes you'll get child `exit()`ing and some not.
- Second, `gettimeofday(2)` doesn't get a pointer to a `time_t` value, but a `struct timeval *`, so you are incurring in a buffer overrun (you are writing the timestamp data past the end of the `startTime` variable (`struct timeval` is larger than `time_t`), corrupting the stack.
- third, you add (supposedly, as the data was already wrong) a timestamp to a pointer, making the pointer to point to a garbage point.  After that the pointer is completely useles.  Are you adding apples with pears?
- next, `execvpe()` never returns, when called successfully, so you'll get a message of `"successfully created child process\n"` **only** in case `execvpe()` fails, which is somewhat contradictory.
- finally, as you do a `waitpid()`, it is not necessary to retain the child pid and call `waitpid()` (you can simply call `wait(2)`, as you only create a single child, and you can trust that `wait(2)` will give an error, if the child finally could not be created, e.g. the `fork()` call didn't succeed)  Also, `returnStatus` is composed of more info than just the `exit(2)` value from the child process, so comparing it with `0` is not the proper way to check how did it go in the child.  See `wait(2)` for more info.